# How to send plain SQL queries (and retrieve results) using scala slick 3

Tags: sql, sqlite, scala, slick

I am trying to make a class that has methods that can send and get data to an SQLite db using plain sql queries. This unfortunately does not work. I do not want to use the withSession implicit parts.

```
import slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.api._
import slick.lifted.TableQuery
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    class DBops {
  val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:sqlite:S:/testing/testdb.sql",driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")

def getData(TableName: String):Future[(Int,Double,String)]={
    db.run(sql"""select * from $TableName """.as[(Int,Double,String)])

}

}
```

The following error is thrown:

type mismatch;  found   : slick.profile.SqlStreamingAction[Vector[(Int, Double, String)],(Int, Double, String),slick.dbio.Effect]  required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[(Int, Double, String),slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]   DBops.scala

Comment: The problem is that the generated code will be 
`select * from 'some_table'`.

Comment: I wonder if my answer was helpful and I understood your problem correctly?

Comment: Answer was helpful but didn't address the question. However I managed to solve it on my own.

Comment: Good to hear! I didn't actually notice the Seq missing from the type :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized I was missing a Seq in the return type:

```
def getData(TableName: String): Future[Seq[(Int,Double,String)]] = {
  db.run(sql"""SELECT * FROM $TableName """.as[(Int, Double, String)])
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `sql"..."` with any `String` content using `#$tableName`:

```
db.run(sql"SELECT * FROM #$tableName".as[(Int, Double, String)])
```

Please remember: don't ever take the `tableName` as a user input - otherwise, there is a great risk for SQL injection. The normal `$value` solves these problems for you.

Read Slick manual (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html#splicing-literal-values)

> ... sometimes you need to splice literal values directly into the statement, for example to abstract over table names ... You can use #$ instead of $ in all interpolators for this purpose ...

Comment: Won't be taking it as a user input this is backend only, Is there any way in slick to NOT have to predefine the column types?

Comment: You mean the `sql"select...".as[(String, Int)]`? Since you're programming Scala it is very important that you determine the types beforehand - that's type safety. Basically you can use tuples with any "primitive types" or you can create your own `implicit` `GetResult`. Read more: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html#result-sets

Plus: I can't see any reason why you could not create a `GetResult` which would create a list by just calling `rs.next` over the result set but I could not find any reference for that.